# Не соединяется с GPS на некоторых устройствах

Tags: java, android, геолокация, gps

Всем привет. Имеется приложение с геопозиционированием. Проверялось на нескольких устройствах все работает, местоположение определяет быстро, на устройствах без gps модуля тоже находит местоположение по agps. Проблема в том что некоторые пользователи усердно жалуются на то что приложение так и не соединяется c gps, а вся суть приложения раскрывается только после установки GPS соединения. Так же слишком большое количество удалений приложения после установки, думаю по той же причине. Ниже приведу код ответственный за GPS соединение, может я что то проглядел в нем? Подскажите пожалуйста.

```html
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {                             
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);                                           
        setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);                                       
mLocationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE); 
      }  

@Override
    protected void onResume() {                                                         
        super.onResume(); 
         ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo networkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        
         Criteria criteria = new Criteria();                                         
        criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);                                               
        criteria.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.POWER_LOW);                                          
        criteria.setAltitudeRequired(false);                                                        
        criteria.setBearingRequired(true);                                                          
        criteria.setCostAllowed(false);                                                             
        String provider = mLocationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);                         
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return;
        }
        mLocation = mLocationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);                                
        mLocationListener = new MyLocationListener();                                               
        mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 100, 0, mLocationListener);               
        showCurrentLocation(mLocation);                                                            
    }
    
        public void showCurrentLocation(Location location) {                                     
        if (location != null) {                                                                    
            currentLat = location.getLatitude();                                                    
            currentLon = location.getLongitude();                                                   
        }
    }
    
    
    public class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {                     
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        
        myLat = location.getLatitude();                                               
        myLon = location.getLongitude();
        
        }
        
        public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle b) {
        }                                                                                           
        public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {
        }                                                                                          
        public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Судя по всему нет коннекта из-за того, что система не дала доступ к GPS, судя по коду:

```
if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return;
        }
```

Вы просто сразу рубите на корню дальше всю работу.

В случае если системой закрыт доступ вашему приложения к GPS, то вам нужно выполнить запрос на разрешения доступа.

Как пример можно сделать это вот так:

```
public static final int REQUEST_LOCATION = 7
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission( this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
           ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[] {
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION }, REQUEST_LOCATION);
    }
```

В случае если нет прав, пользователю покажется уведомление с запросом в выдаче разрешения право на использование GPS вашему приложению.

Данное решение применимо для `Android OS 6 и выше`

Comment: Да кстати, посмотрел отзывы, в основном проблема у людей Androidom выше 6 версии. Пытаюсь использовать Ваш пример, LocationService подсвечивается красным? не могу понять почему